# How to prevent on going back to Fragment in android

Tags: android

How to prevent on going to previous Fragment on press device back button .I dont want to go to previous fragment on device back press neither close app on device back press.

Comment: At least show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Place this in your Main Activity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1 ) {
                this.finish();
            } else {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this (this.finish()) going to end the app? I thought the OP doesn't want the app closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


}
```